# Debian system hangs when changing Wi-Fi network connections

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

I have a laptop running Debian Stretch, and it's been installed for about a year. Since recently, the graphical environment (GNOME) completely hangs when changing network connections (switching access points), except I can still move the mouse around in frustration. I can still use other ptys and even re-login from the graphical one, but the graphical system is completely unusable for a couple of minutes. It seems to happen mostly with wireless connection changes. This happens with or without NetworkManager running.

Checking the syslog and top reveals nothing suspicious. Is there anything else I should check or is there a way to fix this?

Here is the output from journalctl around the time of a long freeze: http://pastebin.com/cFBZsikk

Comment: I mentioned that it seems to be when switching wireless access points.

Comment: Problems that show up on hardware events are usually caused by the kernel or the hardware itself. Did you install a newer Kernel recently? If yes, try using a slightly older kernel to narrow down possible causes.

Comment: I added a log snippet.